# How to access the value of a radio button that is checked using YUI?

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, yui

i have following radio button structure ...

```
<div id="test">
  <input name="test1" value="a" type="radio">
  <input name="test1" value="b" type="radio">
  <input name="test1" value="c" type="radio">
</div>
```

how would i go about retrieving the value of any checked radio button?

i have checked the YUI documentation an there is not really any good example.

I would also like to know how to get the element by input name in YUI?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In YUI 3:

```
var value = Y.one("#test input[name=test1]:checked").get("value");
```

In YUI 2:

```
// the null, null, null, true is optional, but returns only the first match
var input = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsBy(function (el) {
                return (el.name === 'test1' && el.checked);
            }, 'input', 'test', null, null, null, true);

var value = input.value;
```

Comment: Luke, you are my hero of the day! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! I hate YUI 2, I am so used to jquery, and YUI 3 looks like it has adopted a lot of things from there, but unfortunatly I have to use YUI 2 ...

Comment: @Luke Just looking at this answer. I am a beginner so excuse me if I'm mistaken, but doesn't the getElementsBy() method have 6 parameters instead of 7? http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Dom.html#method_getElementsBy

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to your ButtonGroup, you can do like this (in YUI 2):

```
var buttonGroup = new YAHOO.widget.ButtonGroup("test"); 
var button = buttonGroup.get("checkedButton");
var value = button.get('label');
```