# YUI Squarespace CSS manipulation

Tags: css, input, radio-button, yui, squarespace

I am relatively new to Squarespace and using YUI (Yahoo! User Interface Library), and I need some help being able to target and change `"input[type=radio]:checked"` to take on the CSS styling `.menuradio {text-decoration:none !important; border-bottom: 4px solid #000;}`

That said, I am having trouble targeting this piece of code with just CSS:

```
<div class="sqs-block menu-block sqs-block-menu" data-block-type="18" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955">
  <div class="sqs-block-content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1414597475438_1924">
    <div class="menu-wrapper menu-style-classic" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1414597475438_1923">
      <input type="radio" name="menu-selector-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" id="menu-select-all-day-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" class="menu-select-button">
      <input type="radio" name="menu-selector-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" id="menu-select-brunch-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" class="menu-select-button menuradio">
      <input type="radio" name="menu-selector-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" id="menu-select-dessert-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" class="menu-select-button">
      <input type="radio" name="menu-selector-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" id="menu-select-wine-list-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" class="menu-select-button">
      <input type="radio" name="menu-selector-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" id="menu-select-gluten-free-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" class="menu-select-button">
      <div class="menu-selector" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1414597475438_1922">
        <label id="navbuttontop" for="menu-select-all-day-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" class="menu-select-labels menu-label-all-day-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3 menuradio">ALL-DAY</label>
        <label id="navbuttontop" for="menu-select-brunch-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" class="menu-select-labels menu-label-brunch-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3 menuradio">BRUNCH</label>
        <label id="navbuttontop" for="menu-select-dessert-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" class="menu-select-labels menu-label-dessert-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3 menuradio">DESSERT</label>
        <label id="navbuttontop" for="menu-select-wine-list-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" class="menu-select-labels menu-label-wine-list-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3 menuradio">WINE LIST</label>
        <label id="navbuttontop" for="menu-select-gluten-free-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3" class="menu-select-labels menu-label-gluten-free-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-28f6eb3b-5f85-4155-a233-f0c262fef2a3 menuradio">GLUTEN-FREE</label>
      </div>
```

...

What class should I be targeting before the input?

Am I on the right track by using this script?

```
Y.all('input:checked').addClass('menuradio');
```

or

```
Y.all('label').addClass('menuradio');
```

or

```
Y.one('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955 input[type=radio]:checked').addClass('menuradio');
```

or

```
Y.all('.menu-wrapper .menu-style-classic input[type=radio]:checked').addClass('menuradio');
```

?

Nothing seems to be working...

Thanks in advance for any input ;)

Comment: looks pretty much duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376002/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-radio-button-that-is-checked-using-yui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it (probably already did by now). This should work:

```
Y.all('input[type=radio]:checked').addClass('menuradio');
```

Do keep in mind [YUI is dying](http://yahooeng.tumblr.com/post/96098168666/important-announcement-regarding-yui) and due to that Squarespace will probably change it in the future, although [it may take a while](http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/58459/what-does-yahoo-dropping-yui-mean-for-squarespace). But still, I mean, I don't see any reason to not use jQuery instead of old dead YUI! ;P